# Sort python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

I have this dictionary:

```
a = {(u'A', 4): [u'alpha', u'beta', u'gamma'],
     (u'B', 2): [28, 29, 28],
     (u'C', 5): [u'Yes',u'Yes', u'Yes'],
     (u'E', 1): [u'delta', u'omega', u'eta'], 
     (u'F', 3): [u'No', u'Yes', u'No']}
```

I would like to sort it and get:

```
a = {(u'E', 1) : [u'delta', u'omega', u'eta'],
     (u'B', 2) : [28, 29, 28],
     (u'F', 3) : [u'No', u'Yes', u'No'],
     (u'A', 4) : [u'alpha', u'beta', u'gamma'],
     (u'C', 5):[u'Yes',u'Yes', u'Yes']}
```

Sort by key, but in my case, I have a `tuple`. And I want to sort the dictionary by the number into the `tuple` (`key[1]`).

Comment: You may use @liuzhijun advice, sorting with key=operator.itemgetter(1)

Answer (score 4):

you can use `collections.OrderedDict` python module

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda t:t[0][1]))
OrderedDict([((u'E', 1), [u'delta', u'omega', u'eta']), ((u'B', 2), [28, 29, 28]), ((u'F', 3), [u'No', u'Yes', u'No']), ((u'A', 4), [u'alpha', u'beta', u'gamma']), ((u'C', 5), [u'Yes', u'Yes', u'Yes'])])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {(u'A', 4): [u'alpha', u'beta', u'gamma'], 
     (u'B', 2): [28, 29, 28],
     (u'C', 5): [u'Yes',u'Yes', u'Yes'], 
     (u'E', 1): [u'delta', u'omega', u'eta'], 
     (u'F', 3): [u'No', u'Yes', u'No']}

b = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x:x[0][1]))

print b
```

Answer (score 0):

python's `sorted(iterable)` function has an optional parameter, `key`, which takes a function that is applied to one argument. The key function is applied to each element of the iterable, and those results are sorted.

So, you would have:

```
sorted_dict_keys = sorted(a, key=lambda pair: pair[1])
#[(u'E', 1), (u'B', 2), (u'F', 3), (u'A', 4), (u'C', 5)]
```

in contrast to

```
sorted_dict_keys = sorted(a)
#[(u'A', 4), (u'B', 2), (u'C', 5), (u'E', 1), (u'F', 3)]
```